# Adding dynamic input boxes for different fields in the same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am terrible with javascript and do not understand much of it. I need to add text boxes (3-4 of them for different type of inputs) and a few select boxes to a form that I am working on currently so I turn to google for help. This is what I found,

HTML

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[0]"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext['+ x +']"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

});
```

and working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tymb85ob/)

I need a few more dynamic fields which may require a text box or a select box with different properties and name.

I have a field attribute, devices, operating system on my form and want to have dynamically included textboxes for all of them.

**EDIT:-** Someone just answered and it hit me that maybe I did not explain clearly so let me build a scenario where I have three text box, name = attribute, name = device, name = operating system in a form and I wish to add 2 boxes for attribute, 3 boxes for device and 5 boxes for operating system. How do I manipulate the script above to get 2 boxes for attribute, 3 for device and 5 for operating system

How do I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want checkbox to be generated or textbox? And on what basis you need to generate those? like a button click or something?

Comment: use comments instead of answers to ask questions. i did not get what you are trying to ask. and where did checkbox come in from.